# Cannot deploy WAR in jetty 9.4.16.v20190411: receiving FileNotFoundException for jar that is in the war under WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I have an embedded Jetty running and recently had to upgrade to version 9.4.16.v20190411, however the WAR file no longer deploys with the following error message:

```
2019-04-17 11:37:13.054:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@657c8ad9{root,/,jar:file:///D:/SLX/Agent/webapps/root.war!/,UNAVAILABLE}{D:\SLX\Agent\webapps\root.war}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry WEB-INF/lib/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar!/ not found in D:\SLX\Agent\webapps\root.war
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:147)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.getTlds(MetaInfConfiguration.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.scanForTlds(MetaInfConfiguration.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.scanJars(MetaInfConfiguration.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.linxberg.timelogix.service.App.main(App.java:49)
```

I'm using the following startup code for the embedded webserver:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    File loc = findWebappsDir();

    if (loc == null)
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find webapps directory.");


    DeploymentManager dm = new DeploymentManager();
    WebAppProvider wap = new WebAppProvider();

    //prefer THIS loader over child loaders, the opposite of 
    //what J2EE specs, but that doesn't allow our configuration overrides to work correctly
    wap.setParentLoaderPriority(true); 
    wap.setMonitoredDirectories(List.of(loc.getAbsolutePath()));
    wap.setScanInterval(30);
    dm.addAppProvider(wap);

    ContextHandlerCollection chc = new ContextHandlerCollection();

    server = new Server(8080);
    dm.setContexts(chc);

    server.addBean(dm);
    server.setHandler(chc);
    server.start();
}
```

Note that the file is indeed there, although I suspect it has something to do with the way jetty is scanning for tlds (note that this app does not use JSP at all).

Comment: Sounds like you are preventing  the webapp from unpacking itself into the servlet working directory.  Are you using a context xml deployable for that webapp/war? (oh, and your comment about ParentLoaderPriority is wrong/backwards, as that's what standard Jetty does already on environments like OSGi and JPMS, with configuration overrides)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I should point out this is a major upgrade for jetty, the previous version I was using was 6.  Also I don't have the server configured to explode WARs and am not using a context xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your upgrade to Jetty 9.x (from Jetty 6.x) you also upgraded your Servlet support version.

From Servlet 2.5 (in Jetty 6) to Servlet 3.1 (in Jetty 9).

This means the container now has more stuff to do when starting a webapp.

The one impacting you right now is the introduction of  [`javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) (in Servlet 3.0).

There are many `ServletContainerInitializer` (SCI) implementations present in Jetty 9.x, each one can declare an optional [`@HandlesTypes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/HandlesTypes.html) which will list what kinds of annotations and/or classes that SCI is interested in being notified about in the [`ServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html#onStartup-java.util.Set-javax.servlet.ServletContext-).  This means at startup, Jetty must scan webapp container classes (`WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`), and Server Container jars (Server ClassLoader) to find any and all matching classes for the declared `@HandlesTypes`.

This scan is a requirement of Servlet 3.0.

In short, you cannot prevent expanding of the WAR file if you also have jar files in `WEB-INF/lib`, as Java does not support nested unpacking of jar file. Said another way, you cannot use `JarFile` to walk a JAR file that's in another JAR file. (the `JarURLConnection` in your stacktrace is due to the call [`JarURLConnection.getJarFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html#getJarFile--) which allows for walking the JAR file contents, needed for properly bytecode scanning of the JAR)

*An alternate option: QuickStart ...*

You can opt to use Jetty [quickstart](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-webapp.html) and pre-compute the scan at build time and embed it within your war files, using that generated quickstart instead of scanning for content at runtime.

Comment: This explanation is what I needed. I changed it to explode the WAR and it starts up fine.  It's slightly slower this way as stated in the jetty documentation, but overall it's no big deal as the web app takes a long time to start anyway.